# Persist object in C# .NET Web Service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services

Am stuck on what am sure is a fundamental and easy to solve problem in WCF, just need to be guided towards the right way.

I have a large object (which is actually a trained text classifier) that I need to expose through a Web Service in C# .NET. The classifier object can be loaded from disk when the service initially starts, but I don't want to keep loading it from disk for every request (the object that services requests currently occupies about 6 GB in memory, and it takes a while to keep loading it from disk for every request), so instead **I want to persist that object in memory throughout all requests to that web service**, and **the object should only be loaded when the service starts** (instead of loading it when the first web request triggers it).

How would I go about doing that?

**Thanks** for any help!

Comment: Are you planning to host on IIS, or in your own [ServiceHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehost.aspx)?

Comment: IIS ideally, but am easy if another option makes more sense.

Comment: Well, personally, I would use IIS if I were going to expose this to the outside world, but it's easier to maintain state within a Windows Service that exposes a web service using a ServiceHost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to create your service as a [singleton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163590.aspx#S6). This involves specifying `InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single` in a `ServiceBehavior` attribute on your service class definition.

**However** it is *very* questionable if sending a 6GB object over the wire using WCF is advisable. You can run into all sorts of service availability issues with this approach.

Additionally, singletons are not scalable within a host (can be only one instance per host), although you can host multiple singleton services and then load-balance the requests.

Comment: Thanks for the reply hugh, am not actually sending the 6GB object... all I need to do is ensure that this object is loaded before any requests come to the web service (so loaded in the initialization stage), and that all requests will be serviced using this one object (which is about 6GB in size), rather than each request creating its own separate object. I think you are correct and Singleton services is the way to go!

Comment: @ToOsIK Probably a good idea to update your question. It did look like you were trying to send a 6GB object via WCF.

Comment: You will probably need to self host with ServiceHost for your scenario.  See @hugh singleton link "Perhaps initializing the scarce resource the singleton manages takes too much time and you would not want to penalize the first client."

Comment: @OffHeGoes I think you are right, am going to have to go through the self host approach along with a Singleton class one in order to get this to work, as per comish's suggestion.

Comment: @ToOsIK Yeah, I think that is the answer.  I might also be tempted to leave out the Singleton WCF stuff and instead marshall access to the 6GB uber-object myself (static, thread-safe).  That way in future I could scale it up and have multiple 6GB objects in memory (if server is up to it!).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @OffHeGoes, am going to try that first.

Answer (score 3):

The way I've done this in projects that I've had the problem with in the past is to self host the WCF service inside a Windows Service.

I've then set the data storage object up inside the service as a singleton that persists for the life of the service. Each WCF service call then gets the singleton each time it needs to do something with the data.

I would avoid running in IIS simply because you don't have direct control of the service's lifetime and therefore don't have enough control of when things are disposed and instantiated.

Comment: I agree, I've had countless issues with controlling a service's disposal and instantiation, do you have any literature on self hosting a WCF service inside a Windows Service?

Comment: Microsoft has a pretty decent introduction to it in their [How to: Host a WCF Service in a Managed Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758.aspx) article; if it would help, I'll also update my answer with some code.

Comment: thanks for your answer, and for pointing me towards the Win Service approach. Since hugh's answer is more fitting to the question I asked I've accepted his as the correct answer to the question, although your comment is an absolute necessity if I want to ensure stability of my service. Thanks!

Comment: You're most welcome - I agree entirely (in fact, I voted Hugh's answer up myself!)